# bootstrap row-fluid and image grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am going to build an image gallery thumbs. there might be 5-15 thumbs in the page.

My markup is this:

```
<div class="container>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <h4 class="underline"><span>Recent images</span></h4>

        <div id="portfolio" class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg">
           </div>
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg">
           </div>     
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg">
           </div>     
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/4.jpg">
           </div>     
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/5.jpg">
           </div>     
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/6.jpg">
           </div>     
           <div class="span3">
                <img src="img/portfolio/7.jpg">
           </div>     
           ...
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: miss aligned thumbs]

This is not working because the bootstrap is only removing the `margin-left` from the `first-child`.

I know! that I just have to put 4 elements of span3 in a `row` but 
the question is How can I handle the situation that the thumbs are coming from a PHP script, and there are more than 4 thumbs?

Am I supposed to re-iterate for each 4 elements, and make another row-fluid container?

I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your PHP code needs to result in HTML that closes one row, and starts a new row, every 12 "spans":

```
<div class="container>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <h4 class="underline"><span>Recent images</span></h4>

        <div id="portfolio">
          <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>     
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>     
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid"> 
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>     
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>     
             <div class="span3">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/sSAx2/ for a side-by-side comparison of your code and mine. You'll notice that I also split out your `<div id="portfolio" class="row-fluid">` into `<div id="portfolio">` and `<div class="row-fluid">` so that `#portfolio` will be a container for one or more rows of images.

Comment: Also, check out Bootstrap's Thumbnails (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) you might want to use that for organizing your images.

Answer (score 0):

For me, having the images within same div with span3 class worked.
    
    
    Recent images

```
<div id="portfolio">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
</div>  
</div>
<div class="row-fluid"> 
<div class="span3">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSlkfizo8Zj0MGNAt2p9g4JFnjOT4017-sR0Cjodujh5Yqb8JJ">
</div>     

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```